# Powershell equivalent of bash's $NF

Tags: powershell, awk

Someone wanted me to convert his bash code into powershell. I thought I could do it until I came across a weird built in variable called `$NF` which I think reads the lines of the logger? I am not sure how it works but because of it, it stops me from converting this bash script into powershell.

The specific two lines I am having a hard time with:
bash script

```
curl -c ./cookie -s -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${fileid}" > /dev/null
curl -Lb ./cookie "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=`awk '/download/ {print $NF}' ./cookie`&id=${fileid}" > ${filename}
```

but I am not sure what to write for `$NF` in powershell. The other variables, I know how to convert, just not this built in $NF variable to download the item from google drive.

Comment: `$NF` belongs to `awk` not `bash`. `$NF` contains content of last column.

Answer (score 2):

As @Cyrus commented, $NF belongs to awk, not Bash.

Good news though:  it should make working thru the equivalent really easy, since you can just run awk from PowerShell.

Since you can *also* call curl directly, I'll just modify the example you have.

```
# Assigning this to a variable for readability
$curlArg = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(
      <#

      This is a PowerShell subexpression.
      the output of this subexpression will be included in the string
      (multiple outputs will be separated by ' ' )
      Executables may return multiple lines of output (aka multiple outputs), but this case looks like it will only return one line.
      If you need to combine the .exe's output, try -join.
      #>
       awk '/download/ {print $NF}./cookie'
   )&id=$fileid"

curl -Lb ./cookie $curlArg > $filename
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: ah, but it is in fact multiple outputs.  `"$('a', 'b', 'c')"` proves it.

If I'm being more technical, they're not joined by spaces (per se).  They're joined by `$ofs` (output format specifier), which is set to space by default and almost never changed.

Comment: if I run awk in powershell directly it says it can't find it like so: `The term 'awk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function`

Comment: Is awk in your $env:PATH?

Can you find a command named awk?

Alternatively, if I could take a look at what awk is actually matching _against_ that might help.  It would be pretty simple to construct a PowerShell alternative.

Comment: I not sure what you mean by `matching against`. I assume you mean what is the `$NF` variable which I don't know is either. However I can run the code on a mac and maybe throw in an echo to see what it comes out to and extrapolate from there.

Answer (score 1):

I think more to the point of the general question about awk's magic variable NF -- number of fields on the line -- and its use in $NF -- the field at the rightmost position on the line is to note that Powershell's arrays can reference the final position using the index -1. (Perhaps easily remembered with: indexes 1, 2, 3... are from the left; indexes -1, -2, -3 are from the right.)

So as an example this morning I used:

```
 ipconfig | Where-Object {$_ -match 'IPv4 Address'} | %{($_ -split "\s+")[-1]}
```

to extract the IP addresses from the rightmost positions.

(I haven't worked out the specific curl example above -- in powershell I usually use  Invoke-WebRequest in place of curl, but I think I've answered the $NF question and solving the specific question could proceed from there.)